# axlsx_rails excel report format breaks in windows

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, axlsx

Am using axlsx_rails gem with activeadmin to export formatted excel report
This format is working fine in Ubuntu LibreOffice but the styles breaks in windows OS.

> This is the proper aligned format in Ubuntu.

[image]

> But below this image is from Windows that header border and spacing
>   not aligned properly

[image]

My code is here.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.0.1'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.0.0'
```

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

> Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls

**app/admin/job.rb**

```
member_action :export_lease_abstract, method: :get do
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  render xlsx: 'export_lease_abstract_new_format', filename: 'lease_abstract_new_format', disposition: 'inline'
 end
```

**sample view file - export_lease_abstract_new_format.xlsx.axlsx**

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
header_style = wb.styles.add_style :sz => 14, :name => 'Times New Roman', :b => true, :alignment => {:horizontal => :center, :vertical => :top, :wrap_text => true}, :bg_color => "C0C0C0", :fg_color => "000000"
property_style = wb.styles.add_style :b => true, :sz => 12, :name => 'Times New Roman', :border => { :color => 'FF000000', :style => :thin }
sub_header_style = wb.styles.add_style :b => true, :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :border => { :color => 'FF000000', :style => :thin }
content_title_style = wb.styles.add_style :b => true, :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman'
content_value_style = wb.styles.add_style :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :left}
content_title_top = wb.styles.add_style :b => true, :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :left, :vertical => :top}
content_wrap_text = wb.styles.add_style :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :left, :vertical => :top, :wrap_text => true}
content_title_center = wb.styles.add_style :b => true, :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :center}
content_title_right = wb.styles.add_style :b => true, :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :right}
rent_value_center_style = wb.styles.add_style :sz => 8, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :center}
rent_value_right_style = wb.styles.add_style :sz => 10, :name => 'Times New Roman', :alignment => {:horizontal => :right}

border = wb.styles.add_style :border => { :color => 'FF000000', :style => :thin }
gray_cell = wb.styles.add_style  :bg_color => "C0C0C0", :fg_color => "FF"

wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Lease Abstract") do |sheet|
  sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false
  sheet.column_widths 5.2, 32.5, 12, 14, nil, 15, nil, nil, 5.2

  sheet.add_row [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], :style => gray_cell
  sheet.add_row [nil, @job.la_project.name, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], :style => [gray_cell, header_style, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, gray_cell], :height => 20
  sheet.merge_last_row columns:["B","H"]

  # img = File.expand_path('../../../assets/images/hds-logo.png', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  # sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
  #  image.width=100
  #  image.height=50
  #  image.start_at 0, 0
  # end

  sheet.add_row [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], :style => [gray_cell, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, gray_cell], :height => 12
  sheet.add_row [nil, lease_information.try(:tenant_name), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 'Lease Abstract', nil], :height => 17, :style => [gray_cell, property_style, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, property_style, gray_cell], width: 10
  sheet.merge_last_row columns:["B","G"]

  sheet.add_row [nil, "PARTIES:", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], :height => 12, :style => [gray_cell, sub_header_style, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, gray_cell]
  sheet.merge_last_row columns:["B","H"]
  # sheet.column_info.first.width = 30
  sheet.add_row [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], :style => [gray_cell, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, gray_cell], :height => 8
    sheet.add_row [nil, "Tenant Name:", lease_information.try(:tenant_name), nil, nil, "DBA:", lease_information.try(:dba), nil, nil], :style => [gray_cell, content_title_style, content_value_style, nil, nil, content_title_style, content_value_style, nil, gray_cell]
    sheet.merge_last_row columns:["C","E"]
    sheet.merge_last_row columns:["G","H"]
    # sheet.column_info.first.width = 30
    sheet.add_row [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], :style => [gray_cell, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, gray_cell], :height => 8
end
```

How to fix this format to look same in all the os.